# Keeping socket connections in an Array and using them - Java

Tags: java, sockets, serialization

Is it possible to keep each incoming socket connection in an array and use each whenever we need in Java?

I tried the following Array structure but it throws `Exception in thread "ServerHandler-0" java.lang.ArrayStoreException: java.net.Socket`

My array looks like this:

```
 Object[][] requests;
```

And i insert objects into this as follows:

```
 requests[position][0] = o; //o is a Serializableobject
 requests[position][1] = s; // this is the socket instance
```

My intention is to use a socket pulled from the array:

```
Socket s = (Socket) requests[position][1];
OutputStream os = s.getOutputStream();
ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(os);
oos.writeObject(o);
```

thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get rid of the ArrayStoreException I would create a Request-class which holds the information and then store the Request in the array. This way you don't need to do a lot of unnecessary casting and don't need to use Object as the type of the array. I can also recommend you to have a look at `java.nio` where you use channels and selectors to choose desired sockets, which I think is what you are trying to do.

Comment: What kind of array you mean? Casting isn't an issue since this is for an academic project and I somehow need to insert socket instances to an array.

Comment: I meant your requests-array to be `Request[] requests` instead of `Object[][] requests` and the Request object contains the socket instance together with other specific data for that instance.

Comment: If it's a one dimensional array (Request[] requests) how to store both Socket and Serializable object? How do you map the two?

Comment: Your Request-class contains both of them so you don't need to map them

Comment: Does the socket become inactive when it goes into an array like this? When I tried to call `OutputStream os = s.getOutputStream();` on the socket **retrieved from the array** it throws `Exception in thread "Thread-1" java.lang.NullPointerException`

Comment: Are you sure that the object is properly stored and retrieved from the array? It seems like your retrieved socket is null and thus throws the nullpointerexception.

Answer (score 1):

Have you initialized requests[position] to new Object[2]?

Comment: I keep an accepted socket inside the array and do not re-initialize.